# Вывод на экран номинала

Tags: java, android

Есть поле для ввода цифр, а также кнопка `mWithdrawButton`, которая минусует значения от  0 и кнопка `mDepositButton`, которая плюсует значения. Всё это выводиться в `mAmountDisplay`.
Хочется добавить возможность выводить конечное число в кол-ве купюр, например, мы внесли 475, в `mAmountDisplay` показывает что наш баланс 475, а далее: 4 x 100 ; 1 X 50; 1 X 20; 1 x 5 . Подскажите как лучше прописать.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    EditText mAmountInput;
    Button mWithdrawButton;
    Button mDepositButton;
    TextView mAmountDisplay;
    BankAccount mCurrentAccount;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCurrentAccount = new SavingsAccount();

        mAmountInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount_input);
        mWithdrawButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.withdraw_button);
        mDepositButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deposit_button);
        mAmountDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.balance_display);

        mWithdrawButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String amount = mAmountInput.getText().toString();
                mCurrentAccount.withdraw(Double.parseDouble(amount));
                mAmountDisplay.setText("Balance is " + mCurrentAccount.getBalance());
            }
        });

        mDepositButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String amount = mAmountInput.getText().toString();
                mCurrentAccount.deposit(Double.parseDouble(amount));
                mAmountDisplay.setText("Balance is " + mCurrentAccount.getBalance());

            }
        });

    }




    public abstract class BankAccount {
    private ArrayList<Double> mTransactions;
    public static final double OVERDRAFT_FEE = 30;

    BankAccount(){
        mTransactions = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount){
        mTransactions.add(-amount);
        if (getBalance() < 0) {
            mTransactions.add(-OVERDRAFT_FEE);
        }
    }

    protected int numberOfWithdrawals(){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mTransactions.size(); i++) {
            if(mTransactions.get(i) < 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount){
        mTransactions.add(amount);
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        double total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < mTransactions.size(); i++){
            total += mTransactions.get(i);
        }
        return total;
    }
}


    public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    private static final String TAG = "SavingsAccount";
    @Override
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        if(numberOfWithdrawals() >= 3){
            return;
        }
        super.withdraw(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Купюры изначально имеются или просто дробление числа на номиналы? Почему 4х100, а не 2х200, к примеру?

Comment: У вас тип `Double` - "копейки" тоже используются?

Comment: нет, просто дробление числа на номиналы 

Тип Double добавил в качестве теста(его потом уберу) основная задача отображать баланс, который будет представлен в виде кол-ва купюр с n номила.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем вот набросал вам на скорую руку код, он вам даст минимальное кол-во купюр от больших к меньшим(если я правильно понял вашу проблему). Думаю вы разберетесь как применить в вашей задаче.

```
    int [] note = {500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1};
    int [] amountNote = new int [note.length];
    int totalMoney = 12345;
    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < note.length; ++i){
        temp = totalMoney % note[i];
        if(totalMoney == 1){
            amountNote[note.length - 1] = 1;
            break;
        }
        if(temp != 0){
            amountNote[i] = totalMoney / note[i];
            totalMoney = totalMoney - (amountNote[i] * note[i]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < note.length; ++i){
        if(amountNote[i] != 0) {
            Log.d("RESULT", "У вас " + amountNote[i] + " купюр по " + note[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, примерно всё так, тольк я не очень понимаю как подобный код реализовать в 1 классе, может быть в фрагмент как то возможно вообще перенести его?

Comment: вы можете перенести его куда угодно. Добавите эти перменные в ваш класс, в totalAmount подставляете вашу суму.  В вашем случае нужно строку распарсить в инт. Сделать метод из цикла с логикой расчета купюр. И потом вывести результат как вам удобно(я вывел в втором цикле в логи)

Answer (score 0):

как то так предлагаю:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int mBalance = 407;
    int mNominals[][] = {{100,50,10,5,1},{0,0,0,0,0}};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView mTextBalance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBalance);
        TextView mTextNominals = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textNominals);

        mNominals = getNominals(mBalance, mNominals);

        mTextBalance.setText("Balance:" + mBalance);

       for (int i = 0; i < mNominals[0].length; i++) {
           if (mNominals [1][i] > 0) mTextNominals.append("Nominals " + mNominals[0][i] + " x " + mNominals[1][i] + " \n");
       }

    }

    int[][] getNominals (int balance, int[][] nominals) {

        for (int i = 0 ; i < nominals[0].length; i++ ) {
            nominals[1][i] = balance / nominals[0][i];
            balance = balance % nominals[0][i];
        }
     return nominals;
    }
}
```

метод `getNominals()` принимает на вход общую сумму и массив номиналов "купюр". На выходе формирует двумерный массив - первая строка номиналы, вторая строка количество "купюр" этого номинала. При выводе строки с нулевым количеством "купюр" игнорируем.

Если номиналы фиксированные, то массив можно упростить до одномерного и номиналы в метод не передавать, а прямо там инициализировать.

Comment: Да, он делит всё как нужно, но это если только изначально прописать значение int mBalance = 407;
А у меня в коде при добавлении депозита/выдачи депозита, всегда это значение mBalance будет меняться.
Пытаюсь вставить просто Ваш код в свой, идёт конфликт с выводом на экран значений в методах onClick
Немного не понимаю как лучше подправить(

Comment: В вашем случае после строки `mAmountDisplay.setText("Balance is " + mCurrentAccount.getBalance());` напишите: `mNominals = getNominals(mCurrentAccount.getBalance(), mNominals);` полученный массив разделенного на "купюры"  баланса выводите, как считаете нужным. Естественно метод `getNominals()` должен присутствовать в классе, а значения `mNominals[][]` перед этим инициализированы.

Comment: Да, ошибки теперь нету
Но у меня же вывод идёт в 
mAmountDisplay.setText("Balance is " + mCurrentAccount.getBalance());
И идёт просто текущее значение баланса без полученного массива
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно правильно вывести.

Comment: @VadimMorozov Ну вы смотрите ответ и делайте аналогично. Вы же программу пишите, откуда я знаю, как вам там надо правильно вывести.